Outlier Detection in Zero-inflated dataset
I have a feature , more than 85% of its values are 0s. So when i try traditional boxplot method for outlier detection, all the non-zero values are identified as outliers. What modifications can i make here? What else methods are there for identifying the outliers? The 0s are normal to be in dataset, so i cannot drop them or work without them.
